# Salesforce1 layout not showing when linking from visualforce page

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, ios, page-layout, ipad

I have been searching the net to find an answer to a problem I'm facing regarding to loading the right page layout when linking from a Visualforce page.

I have created a Visualforce page which I made available in the Salesforce1 mobile app. On this page it loads appointments for a specific department of our company.
From this page I would like to link to the appointment and want it to open with the Salesforce1 layout.
The problem is that I am getting the right layout on an iPhone, but as soon as I test this on an iPad, the link redirects to the normal Salesforce page.

The code used now is
`<apex:outputLink value="{!'/'&app.id}">App</apex:outputLink>`

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce1 tends to not like standard links or URLs since there is a different navigation mapping mechanism used. There is actually a JavaScript navigation library for Salesforce1 which is the only supported method:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

Could you try using this method instead of the direct URL? You could try the onclick attribute and do something like

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!app.id}');">App</apex:outputLink>
```